# jQuery works in firefox and fails in Internet Explorer

Tags: jquery, html, internet-explorer, firefox

I have return a jQuery which returns the text entered in input element on change event. This jQuery works fine in FireFox but fails in Internet Explorer **(IE9)**.

One thing I realized is when I see SOURCE from IE it shows source of home page only; while FireFox is showing current page source. When I saw the source in "F12 Developer Tools" in IE I am getting all the page HTML source **but following script is not rendered at all**. I am using above script in an ASP.Net MVC application.

Please help...

```
  <script>
      $(document).ready(function () {
          $("#UserName").change(function () {
              alert("Text Entered Is :"+$("#UserName").val());
          });
      });
  </script>
```

Comment: try adding type="text/javascript" script heading

Comment: which versions of IE are you using?

Comment: You mean not even the events firing ? or getting any error?

Comment: Which IE version? Tested IE9 and it worked properly

Comment: I am using IE9. Yes Samy even the event not firing.

Comment: console.info() will works... the problem is with alert

Comment: are there more script librarys other than this. What is in the console? Do you have something on status bar of ie?

Comment: Hey for me its firing the event on focus out. Better to use any other events like keypress, focusout etc.., I am using IE 8 even in firefox same behaviour.

Comment: Is your jQuery being loaded up correctly? Try `console.log($);` and see paste here your output.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code and write the id of the input in lowercase: username, it might work
And load the scripts after the body tag.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {
      $("#UserName").bind("change",function () {
          alert("Text Entered Is :"+$("#UserName").val());
      });
  });
```

Comment: changing from change(function() ... to bind("change") doesn't have any effect here, it's the same thing, only thing useful is the type="text/javascript" which should be used

Answer (score -1):

use the keyup event, IE doesn't fire the change event until the element loses focus.

```
 $("#UserName").keyup(function () {
          alert("Text Entered Is :"+$("#UserName").val());
      });
```

read more

[jquery change event not firing in Internet Explorer (IE)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4823015/jquery-change-event-not-firing-in-internet-explorer-ie)

[jQuery change event not firing in IE when releasing mouse outside of multiple select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4347839/jquery-change-event-not-firing-in-ie-when-releasing-mouse-outside-of-multiple-se)

http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/7698

Comment: That's not true, this is standard event behavior across all browsers

Comment: @RicardoRodrigues:http://forum.jquery.com/topic/ie-change-event-not-firing-on-text-input-after-setting-value-possible-regression

Comment: that a bug in jQuery 1.4.0 ... from 3 years ago, not very helpful